# Peculiar situation with 30 and 70 fps VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, frame-rate

I have a problem with different FPS, but my situation is very specific:

I have a VSE .blend project.

It is just a **slideshow** + little bits of animated (Effect Strip: Transform) stills. Zero "really moving" parts.

It is **30 FPS** and everything is done for that speed.

But it happens that one animation looks good in **70 FPS**. When I render that part of the slideshow in **70 FPS** it is super cool for my tastes. ...

(by the way, this animation is just pure slideshow, no any kind of movement, no key frames)

(More information: this animation consists of fast-changing "pieces" - each of the pieces is **26 frames**. Initially I thought that I will just shorten every piece, but... I want to get exactly the same effect)

But what do I do to combine it with the rest of the video? (If I import **70 FPS** video-file into the project it goes back to **30 FPS**.)

This is kinda stupid situation: I ALREADY HAVE all I want. And it all comes from exactly the same .blend project, so there's nothing fundamentally impossible. Also I don't need to combine strips with different FPS at the same time, those can be (thought of as) completely separate "videos". If you could make completely unrelated parts of the video in different FPS or something it would solve everything. And also, as I said, there's no moving parts, so I don't need any "motion extrapolation" and there's no problems with motion.

It is just too much of a shame that I can't translate the cool effect. I am ready to do it manually, I just need to know that I will get the same thing.

I did math with proportions and tried to change pieces from **26** frames to 11 or 12 [solving the proportion gives **11,(142857)**], it works, but not perfect... maybe, I can't even compare! I can't find exact duration of the clip in properties of the file (Windows). I didn't try speed factor ("Source FPS/Desired FPS = speedfactor" I've seen that formula) or seeking how to stop blender from adjusting **70FPS-lenght** video to **30FPS-length** (so I can at least compare videos or use pre-rendered pieces), but I am asking beforehand because I am in a hurry (this problem already killed two hours that in the end may cost the whole day of delaying the final video).

Can I combine those parts in Youtube? Can Youtube have video in **70 FPS**? In the totally WORST case I can make two different videos, but it is really unwanted. (That I will seek myself later, of course! Sorry for asking, I ask just in case somebody can answer easily)

Thank you very much,

**TL;DR** and again: VSE project. Many animations look good (render good) in **30 FPS**. One particular animation (**"26 x N"** frames) looks good (renders good) if its speed is **70 FPS**. How to get the same speed in **30 FPS** or how to combine it all? You can manually change **26** to any other number of frames.